# Android strings.xml character count

Tags: android, xml, string, android-studio, count

I'm struggling to find a way to count the amount of characters in my strings.xml.

If I select all it only tells me the total amount of ALL characters in the strings, but I want to know the real text characters without `<string name="example">` and `</string>`

Comment: **ur not at all clear.**

Answer (score 2):

Try below one which is recommended

```
int stringLength=getString(R.String.example).trim().length();
```

or Try below method

```
 private int getCount(String str) {

        int counter = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
            if (Character.isLetter(str.charAt(i)))
                counter++;
        }
        System.out.println(counter + " letters.");
        return  counter;
    }
```